When I click the button it just refreshes the page
I am calling the Amadeus API to display flight offers. The API returns JSON which I parse and store in an SQLite database. display_flight_data() queries the database to display flight offers using Pandas. Each flight offer has multiple segments. I created buttons in the flight offers table to show the segments of each flight, however when I click the button it just refreshes the page.
I used session_state so that the page does not refresh on clicking the button but I am having the same issue. Also st.cache_data() and st.cache_resource() don't work:
#Function to query the database and display the flight
def display_flight_data():
    # Initialize session state
    if 'clicked_button_id' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.clicked_button_id = None

    # Connect to SQLite database
    conn = sqlite3.connect('flights.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    # Query flight offers data
    c.execute('''
        SELECT id, lastTicketingDate, price_currency, price_total
        FROM flight_offers
    ''')
    flight_offers = c.fetchall()

    # Query segments data
    c.execute('''
        SELECT
            flight_offer_id,
            departure_iataCode,
            departure_terminal,
            departure_time,
            arrival_iataCode,
            arrival_terminal,
            arrival_time,
            carrierCode,
            flight_number,
            aircraft_code,
            duration
        FROM segments
    ''')
    segments = c.fetchall()

    # Convert to pandas DataFrame for tabular display
    flight_offers_df = pd.DataFrame(flight_offers, columns=[
        'ID', 'Last Ticketing Date', 'Price Currency', 'Price Total'])

    segments_df = pd.DataFrame(segments, columns=[
        'Flight Offer ID', 'Departure IATA Code', 'Departure Terminal', 'Departure Time',
        'Arrival IATA Code', 'Arrival Terminal', 'Arrival Time', 'Carrier Code', 'Flight'  Number',
    'Aircraft Code', 'Duration'])

# Create a dictionary for segments for easy lookup
segments_dict = {}
for _, row in segments_df.iterrows():
    flight_offer_id = row['Flight Offer ID']
    if flight_offer_id not in segments_dict:
        segments_dict[flight_offer_id] = []
    segments_dict[flight_offer_id].append(row)

# Display data in tabular format
st.write('### Flight Offers')
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 = st.columns(5)
col1.write('ID')
col2.write('Last Ticketing Date')
col3.write('Price Currency')
col4.write('Price Total')
# Iterate over the DataFrame and create buttons for each row
for index, row in flight_offers_df.iterrows():
    col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 = st.columns(5)
    col1.write(row['ID'])
    col2.write(row['Last Ticketing Date'])
    col3.write(row['Price Currency'])
    col4.write(row['Price Total'])
    button_label = f'Show Segments {row["ID"]}'
    if col5.button(button_label, key=f"button_{row['ID']}"):
         st.session_state.clicked_button_id = row['ID']

# Check if a button was clicked and display the corresponding segments
if st.session_state.clicked_button_id:
    selected_offer_id = st.session_state.clicked_button_id
    st.write(f'Segments for Flight Offer ID: {selected_offer_id}')
    if selected_offer_id in segments_dict:
        for segment in segments_dict[selected_offer_id]:
            st.write(segment)

conn.close()


There is too much code, that may not be necessary. Could you post just a minimal code but shows the issue.
